# header file for the function poll

Tags: c

I am trying to create a chat application with a non-blocking socket. for this I am supposed to use the `poll()` function. I understand that I've to include the "poll.h" header file but my compiler says "No such file or directory found",On the other hand If I don't include this file my code accepts the structure `pollfd`,it compiles fine but at run time gives me the error that the variable "P is used without being initialised"(I defined "P" to be a `pollfd` variable)
could some one tell me what should I do in this situation...
Is it possible to download header files?
I am working on visual studio 2008.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but I bet Windows doesn't support a POSIX function such as `poll`.

Comment: But it has [`WSAPoll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: when I declared the variable of "pollfd" type,it was ok,and when I was setting the attributes of that variable,I was getting hints from visual c,but when I used the poll() function,I got the error"Undeckared identifier":(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?460259-pollfd-in-windows), you can try using select() instead of poll(), which Windows does not support. You could try to download the libraries and header files that you need, but those may in turn rely on platform-dependent libraries, bringing you back to square one.

You'll want to use the Windows implementation of select(), of course. [Here's the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The header is file is Winsock2.h.

Comment: the header file for select() is "sys/select.h"...I tried to include that and well that too is not found by my compiler:(